# Is there any similar math limerick?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I found this one

$$\frac{(12+144+20)+\left(3 \cdot \sqrt{4}\right)}{7}+(5 \cdot 11)=9^2+0.$$

Which is :

```
A dozen, a gross, and a score

Plus three times the square root of four

Divided by seven

Plus five times eleven

Is nine squared and not a bit more.
```

I think this is very entertaining, thus I wonder if there is any similar limerick/math poem.

Comment: That's probably not even right.

Comment: There once was a number named e. Who took way too much LSD. She thought she was great. But that fact we debate. We know she wasn't greater than 3.
http://www.trottermath.net/humor/limricks.html

Comment: That site also has a good one with an integral that you may like though it's extremely irksome that they've misspelled limericks in the url.

Comment: @oliveeuler You should post your comment as an answer.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: Why was this re-opened?

Comment: @Quinn Why? It is right

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079635/epsilon-delta-quasi-limerick

Answer (score 20):

$$\int_1^{\sqrt[3]{3}} t^2\mathrm{d}t\cdot\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{9}\right)=\ln(\sqrt[3]{e})$$
$$\text{Integral t squared dt,}$$
$$\text{from 1 to the cube root of $3$,}$$
$$\text{times the cosine,}$$
$$\text{of three pi over $9$,}$$
$$\text{equals log of the cube root of $e$.}$$

You can find some more here: http://www.trottermath.net/humor/limricks.html

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692395/mathematical-limerick

Comment: Well I copied it 4 years ago so I'm not surprised. Look it up on archive.org.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that Schnaderhuepfel are the (south?) German equivalent of limericks, I offer the following, which I heard from my father (but the misspellings are my own):

Mir fehlt nur ein Hilfssatz,

Dann bin ich ein Gauss.

Doch den Hilfssatz, den Hilfssatz,

Den krieg ich nicht raus.

Comment: 'I lack only a helpful set, I am a Gaussian, But the alternative set - the auxiliary set, I war not out.' - the limits of machine translation!

Comment: A non-machine translation (not entirely literal and not rhyming): I need only a lemma; then I'm a Gauss.  But that lemma, that lemma; I just can't prove it.

Comment: Hilfssatz (capital H) is 'lemma', and hilfssatz (small h) is 'helpful set' - interesting. But what about the last line - to prove something you need to go to war! Makes perfect sense.

Comment: @mistermarko "Kriegen" can mean to get or to obtain. So the last line literally says "I don't get it [the lemma] out." Also, I've never heard of "hilfssatz" (small h) meaning "helpful set"; in fact, since "set" is a noun, any German word meaning "helpful set" should be capitalized.

Comment: That's why google was confused.

Comment: Is *kriegen* a colloquial term (Umgangssprache), or is it "Hochdeutsch". (I am not sure whether Hochdeutsch is a correct term, but I guess it is understandable what I mean.)

Comment: As far as I know, this meaning of "kriegen" is Hochdeutsch.  But I'm far from an expert on such matters.  I checked one translation site on the web, and the first (of 10) translations that it gave for "kriegen" was "get"; the next 3 were related ("catch, capture, trap") and the remaining 6 were nouns related to warfare.

Comment: By the way, "Satz" is used in mathematical German to mean "theorem", so "Hilfssatz" is literally "helping theorem" or, in better English, "auxiliary theorem", i.e., "lemma".

Comment: @AndreasBlass: if I'm not mistaken, all nouns are capitalized in German; why isn't 'helpful set' then?

Comment: @Alex: I quote from my earlier comment (of July 27): "I've never heard of "hilfssatz" (small h) meaning "helpful set"; in fact, since "set" is a noun, any German word meaning "helpful set" should be capitalized." Note also that all occurrences of "Hilfssatz" in my answer were capitalized. As far as I know, the "helpful set" translation is a figment of some translation program's imagination, and the alleged connection with lower case originated in a comment from mistermarko. A reasonable translation of "helpful set" might be "Hilfsmenge".

Comment: ‘rauskriegen’ (short for ’herauskriegen’? both colloquial?) means ‘to figure (something) out.’ Less often: to find (something) out, or to get (something) out. Many online sources, incl: www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/rauskriegen.html https://dict.leo.org/german-english/rauskriegen https://m.dict.cc/german-english/rauskriegen.html

Comment: @MartinSleziak In case you still care, see the comment above. Also my take: The word "kriegen" and "herauskriegen" are mildly colloquial. The shorter from rauskriegen is even more colloquial. In the sentence there is also the incorrect/informal form "krieg" used,  while "kriege" would be correct. Thus the last sentence in OP is clearly colloquial. "Den kriege ich nicht heraus."   (with 'e' and 'her') is still informal but only mildly so.