# Epsilon-Delta Quasi-Limerick

Tags: limits, soft-question, epsilon-delta, mnemonic

Is this sufficiently logical to commit to memory?  Any suggested edits?

If $x$ is within $\delta$ of $c$,
so $f$ is in $\varepsilon$ of $T;$
work $f$ minus $T$ to $x$ minus $c$;
choose $\delta$ as $\varepsilon$, worked as need be;
then the limit of $f$ as $x$ goes to $c$
is proven to be equal to $T$.

Comment: Change delta to d. If that is epsilon, change it to eta. This makes the meter  and length of the first 2 lines  equal to those of a standard limerick.  I could say more. Looks promising.

Comment: just for completeness: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692395/mathematical-limerick

Answer (score 0):

A limerick has five lines. Your poem has six lines. Yet your title implies your poem is a limerick. Illogical.

Comment: Ok, so a Quasi-Limerick it is.  Questions of poetic form aside, is it logically equivalent to the form of an Epsilon-Delta proof?  First-year calculus student here.

Comment: haha ok, I didn't take this for a serious question (and didn't mean that as a serious criticism). Yeah, the content looks perfectly logical to me, poetic license granted.